# Entity of Response is null

Tags: rest, java-8

currently I am coding on a mock for a rest service we're using. For one case I want to return a 404 with a specific message in the body:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("/bookings")
public javax.ws.rs.core.Response performBooking(final BookingRequest booking) {
    if (shouldfail(booking)) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("specific message in entity").build();
    }
    // some more other cases below...
}
```

If I test the mock with a unit test everything works fine:

```
final String failedMessage = response.getEntity().toString();
```

But if I deploy the rest service and call it, I will get the correct 404 code, but the entity is `null`.

For valid answers I put a `BookingResponse` object in the entity (simple DTO with some IDs in it) and it works for that. Just the string seems to disappear.

Any idea why my string disappears?

Comment: the `404` could be because you are not accessing the correct link at all..  Could you add a log statement right at the begging of your Controller and see if it works?

Comment: @Eugene: Yes, it's talking to my mock, there are several logs in the real code and also several other tests that are talking to the mock for other test cases.